# Firebase onDisconnect re-connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is whether a successful onDisconnect function gets executed by the server even after the client reconnects before the server detects that client got disconnected?

For example- say my onDisconnect function is to remove the node a/b. I disconnect and reconnect again to see a/b present (as the server still hasn't detected that I have disconnected). So now does node a/b be removed as I had asked for when I had disconnected the last time, even though I am connected now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the websocket managed by the SDK gets disconnected for whatever reason, and the SDK manages to reconnect, I would expect that reconnection not to cancel the pending onDisconnect waiting on the server.  It will eventually make the change you requested even if your client app manages to reconnect before the server sees the original connection is broken.  Or in other words, each connected socket has its own onDisconnect on the server - they are not shared or merged in any way.